# How to search mongoId with array using php

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, search

My Mongo collection document is as:

```
Array
(
    [_id] => MongoId Object
        (
            [$id] => 52ddf885f786208bf58020df
        )
    [FirstName] => Aloma
    [State] => AR
    [Title] => AVP
    [Zip] => 71953
    [campaign_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 52fba54fce798c441400002b
            [1] => 52fba687ce798c441400002c
        )

)
```

campaign_id is the array of mongoid's reference to other collection.

How can I get the documents with `campaign_id = 52fba54fce798c441400002b`
Here we have to search `mongoid 52fba54fce798c441400002b` in array of campaign_id.

Comment: `documents ?` what is your expected output ?

Comment: I need to get the count of documents in collection with campain_id array = new mongoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code in mongoDB.

```
db.collection.find(campaign_id:[52fba54fce798c441400002b])
```

It will return the documents that contains [52fba54fce798c441400002b] as campaign_id value exactly.

For example :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52fc4b93633d0c54e662fc75"), "fname" : "test1", "state" : "AR", "campaign_id" : [ 11 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52fc4b8d633d0c54e662fc74"), "fname" : "test1", "state" : "AR", "campaign_id" : [ 12, 14 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52fc4b86633d0c54e662fc73"), "fname" : "test1", "state" : "AR", "campaign_id" : [ 11, 12, 14 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52fc4b7d633d0c54e662fc72"), "fname" : "test1", "state" : "AR", "campaign_id" : [ 11, 12 ] }

> db.scores.find({campaign_id:[11]})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52fc4b93633d0c54e662fc75"), "fname" : "test1", "state" : "AR", "campaign_id" : [ 11 ] }
```

Same thing, you can implement in PHP using php mongo client.

I hope it solves your problem.